# How to use the LIKE keyword in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to write an SQL query using the `LIKE` keyword. It should search the first character or the starting character of my column with the search parameter.

Is there a specific syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE 'X%'
```

This will find all rows where `yourcolumn` starts with the letter X.

To find all that ends with X:

```
...
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE '%X'
```

...and contains an X...

```
...
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE '%X%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select * from table where column like 'c%'
```

where 'c' is the character you want

Answer (score 1):

Here's two examples...

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM tblCustomer
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'B%'
```

The % sign is the wildcard, so this would return all results where the First Name starts with B.

This might be more efficient though...

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM tblCustomer
WHERE LEFT(FirstName, 1) = 'B'
```

Comment: Actually the second version will almost certainly be less efficient as it cannot take advantage of an index on the FirstName column.

Comment: "This *might* be more efficient though..." - we don't know anything about the database or whether there is an index of the field being searched. The execution plan is king.

Comment: Test on random table: LIKE: 2 mins 38 seconds - PATINDEX: 2 mins 39 seconds - LEFT / LEN: 2 mins 20 seconds. Another table would supply different results.

Answer (score 1):

For a parameterized query, which you seem to have ("search the first character [...] with the search parameter"), use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE ? + '%'
```