# SQL and SQLite: how to search field starting with a number

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sinatra

I have a SQL model in which I want to search all words starting with a number.
I can't use regexp since is not supported in SQLite, how can i trick it to have the same results?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to include some source code and expand your question so that we can better figure out how to answer it. Please read this for advice if you need help: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the LIKE keyword in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096935/how-to-use-the-like-keyword-in-sql)

Comment: @Matt Ball, it is not actually duplicate

Answer (score 1):

you can do this hack:

```
@results = YourModel.where("(your_field + 0) > 0")
```

It will return all objects from `YourModel` with `your_field`  started with number that is more than zero (and not a zero)

**Or little more native solution:**

```
@results = YourModel.where("substr(your_field,1,1) IN (?)", (0..9).to_a)
```

It means that **first character of your_field should be one of this numbers**: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: i like the native solution. I was searching for a way to do it exactely that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#glob) in sqlite.

```
Model.filter("field glob ?", '[0-9]*')
```